# how to make tekla controls work inside WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, 3d

I am working with Tekla API and I want it's controls to work inside WPF. Is there any procedure for this? I designed XAML application and need to make it work inside Tekla. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I posted this question, there is no chance of tekla controls to work inside WPF. Now Tekla 2018 version giving support for WPF.

[**here is the link**.](https://developer.tekla.com/tekla-structures/documentation/tekla-open-api-ui-design-wpf)

but WPF won't work completely inside Tekla. It works only for limited features. hope someday entire WPF options work inside Tekla. and let's expect Tekla extends it's features to UWP as well. As it is more advanced than WPF.